# Different length of an array while using 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, arrays, this

I started to learn JavaScript, and I wrote a short piece of code. The final version looks like this:

```js
var johnCalc = {
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tips: [],
  calcTips: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.bills.length);
      if (this.bills[i] < 50) tips[i] = 0.2 * this.bills[i];
      else if (this.bills[i] <= 200 && this.bills[i] >= 50) tips[i] = 0.15 * this.bills[i];
      else if (this.bills[i] > 200) tips[i] = 0.1 * this.bills[i];
    }
    console.log(tips);
  }
}

johnCalc.calcTips();
```

and it works fine. But before I wrote this case which was correct, I made a mistake while using *this* keyword before **tips** array and my code was like that:

```js
var johnCalc = {
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tips: [],
  calcTips: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.bills.length);
      if (this.bills[i] < 50) this.tips[i] = 0.2 * this.bills[i];
      else if (this.bills[i] < 200 && this.bills[i] > 50) this.tips[i] = 0.15 * this.bills[i];
      else if (this.bills[i] > 200) this.tips[i] = 0.1 * this.bills[i];
    }
    console.log(tips);
  }
}

johnCalc.calcTips()
```

It wasn't correct, but what is surprising to me, in the result I received in console 3 array's elements printed (in the correct version it's 5). Why did it work for 3 elements, despite the fact that I needlessly added *this* keyword before the **tips** array? I thought it shouldn't work at all.

I was searching for an explanation, but I couldn't find an answer. Why in the first case a length of tips array is 5, and in the second case it's 3? Could you explain me how *this* keyword works here?

Comment: Your references to `tips` need to all be `this.tips` — including the reference in the final `console.log()` call.

Comment: Your references to standalone `tips` should not work, because `tips` is not a standalone variable

Comment: "and it works fine": It shouldn't. You should get an error: `ReferenceError: tips is not defined`

Comment: It is throwing errors at different points in the code, thus one runs longer than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the code for testing in the console. Then follow the inline comments.

```
  var tips = ["sandwich"]; // This will be window.tips
  var johnCalc = {
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tips: ["pizza"],
  calcTips: function() {
    //tips references the global scope. ie. window.tips
    //tips should show on the console that there is no variable declared.
    //If tips works as "tips" as an array there must be a global tips that is declared.
    //this.tips references johnCalc.tips.
    console.log(window.tips,this.tips);
  }
}

johnCalc.calcTips();
```

The output will be.

> Array [ "sandwich" ] Array [ "pizza" ]